# retrieve data from structure when entering one field value MATLAB

Tags: matlab, structure, field

I have created a structure about patient. Its fields are name, age, etc. I want to be able to retrieve a patient's all info by entering its name or any other unique property. In other words, how can I find the patient's index? Thanks in advance.

```
patient(10).name = 'Chuck';
patient(10).age = 29;

patient(11).name = 'Sarah';
patient(11).name = 28;
```

Answer (score 1):

Structures are not a good data type for doing what you want.

I suggest using a [table](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html?refresh=true). If you have your data in the structure already, call

```
patientTable = struct2table(patient);
```

Then, you get the index as:

```
chucksIndex = find( strcmp( patientTable.name, 'Chuck'))
```

And you get that patient's information as

```
patientTable(chucksIndex,:)
```

(note: if all you need the index for is lookup, you don't need to call find, the logical index from strcmp suffices).

Double-clicking the table in the workspace browser presents the data in an Excel-like fashion. The only thing you'll have to change in your code is accessing the data. Instead of

```
patient(10).name
patient(10).age
```

You write

```
patientTable.name{10}
patientTable.age(10)
```

---

If you do not want to use a table, you can get the index as:

```
chucksIndex = find(strcmp({patient.name},'Chuck'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an error, it should be `patient(11).name = 28;`.

Here is a way this should work. I've started the indexes for Chuck and Sarah at 1.

```
patient(1).name = 'Chuck';
patient(1).age = 29;

patient(2).name = 'Sarah';
patient(2).age = 28;


% Assign to cell array
plist = {patient.name};

% Choose the name of a patient
choose_patient = 'Sarah';

% Find the chosen patient in the list
ix_patient = find(strcmp(plist, choose_patient))

% Get full entry for that patient
patient(ix_patient)
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `patient(11).age = 28`